# Why do we have to multiply by the norm of the derivative of the parametrization to calculate line integral?

Tags: integration

Why do we have to multiply by the norm of the derivative of the parametrization to calculate line integral?

The definition of the line integral is:

$$
\int_\Gamma F\cdot  {ds}=\int_a^b F\left(\alpha(t)\right)||\alpha'(t)||dt 
$$

I don't understand why the derivative comes into play here, could someone help me out with an intuitive understanding, maybe considering only functions $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: Something's missing in the right hand side, there should be a vector multiplying $dt$.

Comment: Right, I mixed up the definitions between scalar field and vector field line integrals. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: I recently attended a summer school in which this question was answered in the following (IMHO) very clear way. Try to define the integral in the most obvious way, that is: $\int_\Gamma F\, ds=\int_a^b F(\alpha(t))\, dt.$ Change parameterization of $\Gamma$ and see that the right hand side is not invariant (one says that it is not "geometric"). The formula you have is the simplest way to obtain a geometric notion of integral.

Answer (score 0):

In a very naive sense s= a(t) then $\frac{ds}{dt}$= a'(t).
So the quantity of $$F(s) \cdot ds= |F(s)|*|ds| cos \theta $$
$$|F(s)|*|\frac{ds}{dt}|dt cos \theta=|F(a(t))|*|\frac{da(t)}{dt}|cos\theta $$
But if the first derivative is always tangent to a curve, then $\theta=0$ and you have the statement:
$$F(s) \cdot ds=|F(a(t))||a'(t)|dt$$